# Own style creation by using TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht

I have given my tag below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\HalfTitle}[1]{\large#1}
\begin{document}
\HalfTitle{Half Title}
\end{document}
```

I need this in HTML output as:

```
<HalfTitle> Half Title </HalfTitle>
```

How can I achieve this? I am using the below tag for HTML conversion:

```
htlatex test "xhtml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"
```

please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--- file.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mytag}
\begin{document}
\mytag{Test 123}
\end{document}
```

--- custom.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\NoFonts
\Configure{mytag}{\HCode{<mytag>}}{\HCode{</mytag>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

--- mytag.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{mytag} 
\newcommand\mytag[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\endinput
```

--- mytag.4ht

```
\NewConfigure{mytag}{2}
\let\tmp:mytag\mytag
\renewcommand\mytag[1]{\a:mytag\tmp:mytag#1\b:mytag}
```

Run:

```
htlatex file.tex "custom,charset=utf-8" " -cunihft"
```

Comment: it works fine, much thanks for your help...............